# EF: How to do effective lazy-loading (not 1+N selects)?

Tags: orm, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Starting with a List of entities and needing all dependent entities through an association, is there a way to use the corresponding navigation-propertiy to load all child-entities with one db-round-trip? Ie. generate a single `WHERE fkId IN (...)` statement via navigation property?

More details
I've found these ways to load the children:

1. Keep the set of parent-entities as IQueriable<T>

   - Not good since the db will have to find the main set every time and join to get the requested data.
2. Put the parent-objects into an array or list, then get related data through navigation properties.
   `var children = parentArray.Select(p => p.Children).Distinct()`

   - This is slow since it will generate a select for every main-entity.
   - Creates duplicate objects since each set of children is created independetly.
3. Put the foreign keys from the main entities into an array then filter the entire dependent-ObjectSet
   `var foreignKeyIds = parentArray.Select(p => p.Id).ToArray();

   var children = Children.Where(d => foreignKeyIds.Contains(d.Id))`
   Linq then generates the desired "WHERE foreignKeyId IN (...)"-clause.

   - This is fast but only possible for 1:*-relations since linking-tables are mapped away.
   - Removes the readablity advantage of EF by using Ids after all
   - The navigation-properties of type EntityCollection<T> are not populated
4. Eager loading though the .Include()-methods, included for completeness (asking for lazy-loading)

   - Alledgedly joins everything included together and returns one giant flat result.
   - Have to decide up front which data to use

It there some way to get the simplicity of 2 with the performance of 3?

Answer (score 0):

You could attach the parent object to your context and get the children when needed.

```
foreach (T parent in parents) {
    _context.Attach(parent); 
} 
var children = parents.Select(p => p.Children);
```

Edit: for attaching multiple, just iterate.

Comment: I think you just described the `1 + N Selects` scenario.

Comment: Im sorry, I didnt understand your question then. You want all the children in 1 db-roundtrip. But lazy-loaded? Lazy-loading implies multiple db-trips.

Comment: No, the question is how to get all of the children of *multiple* parents at one time. You've only shown how to do it for a *single* parent.

Comment: Exactly, that was a short and precise way of putting it. And additionally for many-to-many relationships: Each child should become a single instance shared by all the parents.

Answer (score 0):

I think finding a good answer is not possible or at least not worth the trouble. Instead a micro ORM like [Dapper](https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net) give the big benefit of removing the need to map between sql-columns and object-properties and does it without the need to create a model first. Also one simply writes the desired sql instead of understanding what linq to write to have it generated. `IQueryable<T>` will be missed though.